# Send Query String in RedirectToAction MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirecttoaction

I've two action method in the following controller-

```
public class VisitMasterController 
{
    public ActionResult StartBrVisit()
    {
        string id=(Request.QueryString["id"].ToString(); //value=null here
    }

    public ActionResult BrNotPresent()
    {
         return RedirectToAction("StartBrVisit","VisitMaster" , new { id = "id", name = "name" });
    }
{
```

After Redirect, `Request.QueryString["id"]` returns null.

My default route config is-

```
         context.MapRoute(
         "BR_default",
         "BR/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
         new[] { "OpinionLeader.Areas.BR.Controllers" } //add this line
     );
```

Any help?

Comment: Are you using the default routes with `.../{id}`? And why not just use `public ActionResult StartBrVisit(int id)`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke - yes, there is a default route with name id. I've updated my question. I need to use string here.

Comment: Then just make the method `public ActionResult StartBrVisit(string id)` (and you could add `string name` as well). You `id` value is added as a route value, not a query string value so you could also use `Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]`

Comment: Got the point. Please post it as answer with code snippet (if possible). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have defined a route with a parameter named `id` so when you use `new { id = "id" }`, the `RedirectToAction()` method finds a match and adds the value as a route value, not a query string value (in the case of `name`, there is no match, so its value is added as a query string value). You could access it using

```
string id = (string)Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

However, it would be far easier to add a parameter to your method

```
public ActionResult StartBrVisit(string id)
```